# JQuery/Ajax post in Razor page and redirect to returned view from MVC Action (aka form submitting)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I post a json array to the MVC Action via either JQuery or AJax, and Action handles the request correctly. However, then MVC Action is returning a View and I need to redirect to this View (or replace a body with it) but I don't know how.

So, the action is working well except probably for the returning value:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateGet(List<string> itemIds)
    {
        List<TempItem> items = new List<TempItem>();
        foreach (string item in itemIds)
        {
            items.Add(CallApi.Get(Request.Cookies["jwt"], "tempitems", item.ToString()).Content.ReadAsAsync<TempItem>().Result);
        }
        Invoice inv = new Invoice()
        {
            IsSupplement = items[0].IsSupplement,
            Date = DateTime.Now,
            Employee = CallApi.Get(Request.Cookies["jwt"], "employees/getprofile").Content.ReadAsAsync<Employee>().Result,
            InvoiceItems = new List<InvoiceItem>()
        };

        foreach(TempItem item in items)
        {
            inv.InvoiceItems.Add(new InvoiceItem { Amount = item.Amount, ProductId = item.ProductId, Product = item.Product });
        }
        return View(inv);
    }
```

And the script inside razor page, that collects selected ids and posts them to the action. 
After the post nothing else happens, even the alert is not being called, even though the View page exists and I don't see fails in console.

```
    function CreateInvoice(id) {
        var selected = $('#' + id).DataTable().rows('.selected').data();
        var items = [];
        for (i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
            items.push(selected[i][0]);
        }
        var postData = { itemIds: items };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Invoices/CreateGet",
            data: postData,
            success: function (data) {
                alert("success");
                window.location.href = data.url;
            },
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true
        });
    }
```

**Update**

Well, I gave up that nonsense and stuck to GET request that passes array of ids in the URL. I think I just doing things wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `ActionResult` to `JsonResult`.
And return like this:

```
return Json(new {url: "yoururl", inv: yourdata}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: You use url: "/Invoices/CreateGet" in AJAX call so that you need return JsonResult in your action.

Comment: The thing is that I managed to get success in ajax request and my returned data contains`url` and `invoice` object. I can do `windows.location.href = data.url`, so page redirects to the right place, but how do I also pass the invoice object into this page?

Comment: I saw in your source code, no url in invoice object?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to do nothing in actual page with data returned from ajax call, you shouldn't use ajax call. You can use submit request and redirect page in backend to new page.